# Bootstrap collapse in navbar not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to create simple responsive navbar using bootstrap. I don't know for what reason but collapse navbar isn't working. Have assigned data-target to the collapsable div still nothing works.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">Humanity</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#Menu 1">Menu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Menu 2">Menu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Menu 3">Menu 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `#` in your `data-target.`

**Now it's working fine check snippet**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      
      
       </head>
       <body>
       
     

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">Humanity</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#Menu 1">Menu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Menu 2">Menu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Menu 3">Menu 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```